# Send emails from flutter application without expenses or smtp server and without opening the gmail app

Tags: flutter, dart, email

As the title says, I would like to know if there is any way to send emails without having to use an external service, that charges me for sending the messages, or having to use an SMTP server in which each user has to be registered.
I have also seen pages like email.js but I don't want to have to pay for that if there is a possibility to do it on my own. It is also not useful for me to open the Gmail or messaging application of the device itself since I already know how to do that and it is not what I want.

For better understanding, I will give an example of what I want to do.
What I want is that from my application the user writes a message and from there that email message is sent to several different users from a list, without having to log in or anything, since the emails will be sent from my own email account. gmail that I have specifically created for the application.

I have seen the smtp server but from the information that I have seen that server implies that I have to log in to be able to have the token and that is not what I want because I want that once I configure everything there is no need to do anything else that people receive your messages and that's it.

I don't know if this is possible but I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Sending emails without your user logging in would require you to have either the credentials stored in the app (which is unsafe) or use a custom backend server that will host all the credentials that cannot be extracted. I would advise going with the backend route because it is easier to setup and your application will simply perform a HTTP request to get it done.

From the documentation of the [mailer](https://pub.dev/packages/mailer#server-developers) package, you can implement the server method pretty easily and get it moving. You will have to find a free web hosting service to deploy to.

There would really be otherwise no other way to get what you desire for virtually free.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I understand better now. Well, I will look for information to be able to open my server, since I am quite a beginner.

Anyway, I would like to take this opportunity for another question.

I saw that an article said to use environment variables through an .env file that thanks to this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_dotenv)
It helps you to be able to read this file in your flutter code and says that this way it is protected. Is this true?

Comment: I myself have wasted countless hours trying to figure out ways to protect the secret keys but honestly, it is impossible to do so when an attacker is adamant about finding them. From the dotenv package that you linked, there's this comment on the issues page that should clarify your doubts. Regardless of that, I would suggest encrypting and storing your SMTP user and password in a server that you can fetch and decrypt locally. You can play around with designing an algorithm to generate the encryption key in real time so that your server and client can get matching keys.

Comment: Otherwise, you can keep changing the user/password combination in your server (or pastebin) and make the client retrieve those before every email sending operation. Devise a way to update the server/paste with a new user/password combination in a specific time interval to make it challenging for the attackers. Even this is not feasible to an extent so don't take my advice at face value. It's a game of cat and mouse and there's no perfect way of dealing with this.

Comment: https://github.com/java-james/flutter_dotenv/issues/8#issuecomment-804397913 Sorry I forgot about this. Here's the issue that I was talking about.

Comment: Really, thank you very much for all the help, I can't put your answer as the best one because I don't have enough reputation, but you have clarified many doubts, thanks again.

Finally, I would like to ask you if it is possible for me to create a backend with firebase and store my key there, well I know it is possible, but would that at least be more secure?

Comment: Even that is not very secure because if you monitor the network activity you can easily find out the URL endpoint your app is hitting to get the keys. So, an attacker can also read the response that the firebase server is returning and have access to the keys. Reverse engineering a flutter app is not feasible at the current time. So, you can implement an algorithm that manipulates the data you keep in firebase to get the actual key out of it. Now because your source code is not available to the attackers, they will never know what the actual keys are. This is the best that is possible IMO

Comment: Without a doubt I have tried to do the most difficult thing, the generated appbundle is obfuscated in the way that the flutter developers say is the most efficient, I hope that with that and creating some algorithm like the one you say to manipulate the data it will be safe enough so that if someone manages to violate the security of the application, they have to be a genius or at least take a long time.
Thank you for your answers!!

Comment: You're welcome. Problems like these are kinda exciting, to be honest!